# TYPO3: how to display images in original size

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

**Question**:

How can I setup TYPO3 (env see below) to display images in click-enlarge in the original size and don't resize/crop the image.

**Background**:

I need to display images on some pages/page trees in the original high resolution size when click-enlargeing the image on the page. So there should be no processing of the image for displaying it.

How can this be achieved?

*Just for clarification: I don't want to do this for the whole site. Nor do I want to change any code.
TypoScript, CSS, template additions would be ok.*

**Environment**

TYPO3 8.7.19

Introduction / Bootstrap package

Comment: I think your usecase is the one reported here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77886 there is a solution there in the comments, can you test it?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi thank you so much. Please enter it as solution so that you can get the credit for it. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case is the one reported here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77886

Please add to your TypoScript Setup the code reported on the note #14:

```
lib.contentElement.settings.media.popup.crop.data =
```

Note that this setting will be applied to the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** for **TYPO3 V11** I set in the constants the following value's to override the original 800m, 600m

```
styles {
    content {
        textmedia {
            linkWrap.width = 1920m
            linkWrap.height = 1920m
        }
    }
}
```